# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused(elasticsearch)

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch using this command : `pip install elasticsearch`
After installation I executed the following commands:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
# by default we connect to localhost:9200
>>> es = Elasticsearch()
# create an index in elasticsearch, ignore status code 400 (index already exists)
# but when I run this instruction:
>>> es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400) // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
File "elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 110, in create
params=params, body=body)
File "elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(\
    method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
File "elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 105, in perform_request
raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xM3M>:
        Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by:
            NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xM3M>:
                Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Comment: Does `elasticsearch` runs locally on your machine?

Comment: it is installed using: pip install elasticsearch to run as a python library

Comment: No, what you have installed is only a python client to communicate an existing cluster, which is by default assumes runs on `localhost:9200`.

Comment: Actually I just started learning how to use elasticsearch ... I used this code as a starting point:     https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elasticsearch/2.4.0#downloads

Comment: Look at the official answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you have installed is a Python client which is used for communication between your Python script and existing Elasticsearch cluster.

As mentioned from your comment, at the top of the [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elasticsearch/2.4.0#downloads) you started reading, it says:

> Official low-level client for Elasticsearch. Its goal is to provide
>   common ground for all Elasticsearch-related code in Python; because of
>   this it tries to be opinion-free and very extendable.

You can configure the client the host(s) and port which the cluster is running on, and connect to it and execute commands on that cluster.

In your code, you configured the client to use the default settings which assumes the cluster is running on `localhost` with the default elasticsearch port `9200`.

You need to [Install Elasticsearch on a machine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html), configure it and run it, and then you'll be able to connect your client to the cluster and communicate with it.

Answer (score 3):

Following the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html) is straight-forward and you should be able to get `elasticsearch` up and running. Just to break it down, using `pip3 install elasticsearch` does not create a connection to `elasticsearch`. Follow the steps below to set up, install and start connection:

**Install Necessary Packages**

Since `Elasticsearch` runs on top of `Java`, you need to install the Java Development Kit (JDK). You can check if `Java` is installed by running this command in your terminal:

```
$ java -version
```

If you do not have `java`, you can install the default JDK by:

```
$  sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Run `java -version` to check that `java` is installed

To allow access to your repositories via HTTPS, you need to install an APT transport package:

```
$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```

**Download and install Elasticsearch (on Ubuntu)**

First, update the GPG Key for the Elasticsearch repository using the `wget` command to pull the public key ([from the documentation now](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html)):

```
$ wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the repository to your system:

```
$ echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
```

Now, install `elasticsearch` by first updating the package index then run the installation:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install elasticsearch
```

**Start Elasticsearch**

`Elasticsearch` does not run until you start it. Also, when you reboot your machine, you need to rerun the `elasticsearch` service since it does not start automatically.

To reload the systemd configuration, run:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable the `elasticsearch` service:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```

Now, you can start `elasticsearch`:

```
$ sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

At this point, `elasticsearch` will start everytime you reboot your system.

To test your set up, try running `http://localhost:9200/` on your browser's url bar. You should see some JSON data dumped on your screen. Better still, on your terminal, try:

```
$ curl localhost:9200
```

This completes the setup, installation and how to start the `elasticsearch` service. Now you can try running your commands on the terminal and everything should work fine.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
>>> es = Elasticsearch()
>>> es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
{'acknowledged': True, 'shards_acknowledged': True, 'index': 'my_index'}
```